# How many times can I change a ticket from Copa Airlines?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I have a ticket from Copa Airlines that allows for free changes (it is called an "Economy Full" ticket). However, I need to change the date of my flight. Are there limits to the number of times I can change my flight? Ideally I would be able to change it 2-3 times if the need arises, but I am not sure if that is possible.

Also, if I have to cancel this flight, what is the latest I can do this and still get my money back?

There are [Terms and Conditions](https://www.copaair.com/en/web/us/terms-conditions) on the Copa website but those are about the website itself. The link to "Flexible Cancellations" leads back to the homepage (?).

Comment: https://www.copaair.com/en/web/gs/contract-of-carriage

Comment: Copa's Terms and Conditions of Carriage appear as a downloadable .pdf file named "Contract of Carriage." In that .pdf file, the T&C are shown without a mandatory re-direct to the booking page. Page 14 addresses changes, but does not mention changes at the request of the passenger.